# How to use blob urls with Chromecast?

Tags: javascript, polymer, html5-video, google-cast, bloburls

I am currently experimenting with the `google-castable-video` component of the Google Web Components of the Polymer library. So far no larger issues. But when I try to stream a video, which has a blob-url as source, the stream on the Chromecast starts buffering, but immediatly stops without showing a frame.

Now i am asking myself, if it is even possible to use an url like `blob:http%3A//127.0.0.1%3A8889/fd3e3425-f5ea-48f1-a380-5febf0f071ad` with the Chromecast-SDK. If not, are there any alternative ways to load a local video and stream that with this Web-Component? (Excluding existing tools like Videostream, etc.)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you have provided is pointing to the local loopback so when chromecast receives that, it tries to load that from its own local device and clearly that is not what you want. If you want to serve local content from your sender side, you need to embed a local web server in your sender and serve content using that web server; you can search on StackOverflow for prior posts on serving local content to chromecast.

Comment: The "app" I try to make with the component is (will be) hosted on a server (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog so far for testing). But in my understanding this does not make a diffrence, as I would need the site to host the file (it's a local file loaded with the file input element) right?

Comment: Chromecast needs a URL for a media that it can access (and if one uses a named url, it should be resolvable "externally" as well); that is all it needs to reach the media (plus usual requirements such as CORS for adaptive content, etc).